# Regex inside group

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a csv file I need to import into my db.

Sample input:

> 122545;bmwx3;new;red,black,white,pink

I want the final output to be like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("122545", "bmwx3", "new", "red");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("122545", "bmwx3", "new", "black");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("122545", "bmwx3", "new", "white");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("122545", "bmwx3", "new", "pink");
```

The 4th element is a "sub-csv" with an unknown amount of entries. But always in that format (no ")

Ideally I would like to do this in notepad++ using regex, if not possible I will have to cook up a script.

I think that first I need to make this:

> 122545;bmwx3;new;red,black,white,pink

Look like this:

> 122545;bmwx3;new;red
>
> 122545;bmwx3;new;black
>
> 122545;bmwx3;new;white
>
> 122545;bmwx3;new;pink

My problem is that I don't know to match the *sub*-csv. Is it even possible to do this in *pure* regex (no programming needed)?

Comment: You can replace all `,` with `122545;bmwx3;new;`

Comment: Is the number of colors fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the `122545;bmwx3;new;` part is *not* fixed**

In three steps:

- Get to `red,black,white,pink#LIMIT#122545;bmwx3;new;`: replace `(.*;)([^;]*)` with `\2#LIMIT#\1`
- Create the `122545;bmwx3;new;red` stings: replace

  ```
  (\w+)(?:,|(?=#LIMIT#))(?=.*#LIMIT#(.*))
  ```

  with `\2\1\n` (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gU3gV6))
- Remove the `#LIMIT#...` lines: replace `^#LIMIT#.*` with an empty string

---

**If the `122545;bmwx3;new;` part is fixed**

@hjpotter's idea seems pretty cool, you just new to replace `,` with

```
\n122545;bmwx3;new;
```

---

**What's left**

Replace

```
^(\w*);(\w*);(\w*);(\w*)$
```

with

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("\1", "\2", "\3", "\4")
```

You're good to go !

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not the simplest way, but it works:

Find what: `^([^,]+;)(.+),([^,]+)$`
Replace with: `$1$2\n$1$3`

And click on `Replace all` as many time as needed!